# Reset graphic cards settings to default / Radeon RX 550X

Tags: drivers, 18.04, games, radeon

I bought recently a Lenovo E490. This laptop only comes with Windows 10. So I made a new partition and installed Ubuntu on it. Used manly for programming, but sometimes I playing one or two rounds of CS:GO.

The specs are:

- Intel i7, 8th generation
- 16 gig RAM
- 512 SSD
- Radeon RX 550X / Intel UHD 620

But I only could play on ultra low settings with a resolution of 1600x900.
I figured out, that Ubuntu doesn't used the dedicated rx500x. So I tried to used `switcheroo-control`. Didn't changed. I set `DRI_PRIME=1 steam`. Also didn't brought the beneficial change.

But what all these steps above did, the game crashes without any error and I get thrown to my desktop and the game ended.

I also tried to install the amdgpu-pro driver, but I did that, I couldn't start up ubuntu anymore. Had to remove that from the cli.

So I just want to have the basic setup when I installed Ubuntu 3 months ago.
Is there a reset option? Of course without losing my local git branches, etc. I did every week a backup with `dejavu`.

Comment: That brought me on the right track! Also check out the program `configure-debian`